# C# WMI How to get name of current audiodevice

Tags: c#, wmi

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mo = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_SoundDevice");
                foreach (ManagementObject soundDevice in mo.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("DeviceId"));
                    Console.WriteLine(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
                }
```

With this I can get names of all audiodevices. But how to know which is used right now?

Comment: Would it not be easier if you decide what audio device to use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/)

And then something like this oneliner:

```
string curDevName = new MMDeviceEnumerator().GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia).FriendlyName;
```